# WDK refuses to install, Missing .cab file?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sdk, driver, wdk

Every time I try to install WDK I get this error, I have visual studio 2022 and SDK that downloads with it

[image]

To be fair I've only tried flushing my DNS, deleting temp files, turning off virus protection and using older versions of WDK.

I also get this error message

> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:14]i000: payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:14]i000: payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE to https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/f/7bfc8dbe-00cb-47de-b856-70e696ef4f46/wdk/Installers/39ca279703a01bbec1753d8493becf2c.cab
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:14]i338: Acquiring package: package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationVersioned_x86_en_us, payload: payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE, download from: https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/f/7bfc8dbe-00cb-47de-b856-70e696ef4f46/wdk/Installers/39ca279703a01bbec1753d8493becf2c.cab
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:14]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/f/7bfc8dbe-00cb-47de-b856-70e696ef4f46/wdk/Installers/39ca279703a01bbec1753d8493becf2c.cab' to: 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp{789764C9-F448-4AAE-B98E-0A4B80457B7B}\payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE'
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:14]i000: Retry downloading of payload [payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE] for Package package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationVersioned_x86_en_us
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:34]w343: Prompt for source of package: package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationVersioned_x86_en_us, payload: payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE, path: C:\Installers\39ca279703a01bbec1753d8493becf2c.cab
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:34]i000: payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:34]i000: payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE to https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/f/7bfc8dbe-00cb-47de-b856-70e696ef4f46/wdk/Installers/39ca279703a01bbec1753d8493becf2c.cab
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:34]i338: Acquiring package: package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationVersioned_x86_en_us, payload: payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE, download from: https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/f/7bfc8dbe-00cb-47de-b856-70e696ef4f46/wdk/Installers/39ca279703a01bbec1753d8493becf2c.cab
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:34]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/f/7bfc8dbe-00cb-47de-b856-70e696ef4f46/wdk/Installers/39ca279703a01bbec1753d8493becf2c.cab' to: 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp{789764C9-F448-4AAE-B98E-0A4B80457B7B}\payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE'
> [6C74:851C][2024-02-14T18:05:34]i000: Retry downloading of payload [payD4E8781AD7A6D5A878C26D8C2CAC13CE] for Package package_WindowsDebuggingWDKIntegrationVersioned_x86_en_us
> [6C74:5680][2024-02-14T18:05:36]i000: User canceled setup

when looking through the logs.
Sorry for bad post I'm a bit new here.